# How to make the child process handle SIGSEGV by itself

Tags: segmentation-fault, signals, child-process

I have a program that calls `run` to do something.
In `run` running, which will generate a SIGSEGV and catch this signal and normal return by sigsetjmp/siglongjmp.
However, if i create multiple child processes to run the function `run`, the `run` seems to be unable to catch its own SIGSEGV signal.
Therefore, my question is how does the child process capture its own SIGSEGV and return normally?
Here, my example code.

```
struct sigaction act, oact;
static  sigjmp_buf jmpbuf;
int run(void * arg);
static void sig_handle(int signum, siginfo_t* siginfo, void* context){                 
  siglongjmp(jmpbuf,1);                                  
} 

#define STACK_SIZE (1024 * 1024)
int main()
{
  pid_t pid;
  pid_t pid1;
  char *stack;
  char *stackTop;
  stack = (char*)malloc(STACK_SIZE);
  if (stack == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed\n");  
    exit(-1);
  }
  stackTop = stack+STACK_SIZE;
 
  pid = clone(run, stackTop, CLONE_VM|SIGCHLD, (void*)2);
  if (pid == -1){
    fprintf(stderr,"clone failed\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) 
    run((void *)i);

  if (waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) == -1){    /* Wait for child */
      fprintf(stderr,"clone close failed\n");
      exit(-1);
     }
 
  return 0;
}

int run(void * arg){
  act.sa_sigaction = sig_handle;
  sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
  act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO|SA_ONSTACK;
  if(sigaction(SIGSEGV, &act, &oact)<0)
    exit(-1);

  int args = (uint64_t)arg;
  if(sigsetjmp(jmpbuf,1)==0){
    if(args==2)
        sleep(1);
    *(uint64_t *)0 = 1;
  }else 
    sleep(1);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, if i create multiple child processes

The `clone()` function you are using *does not* create child processes, it creates threads within the current process, all *sharing* the address space with the parent (`CLONE_VM` flag).

While this can be made to work, it's extremely tricky to do this correctly, and there is a high chance that you aren't. In particular, you can not call *any* libc function within the `clone()`d process (and you do call `sigaction()`; that's a no-no).

You also can't use a single `jmpbuf` if it is shared by multiple threads.

The simple solution is to *actually* create child processes (using `fork()`).

Comment: Yes, you are right! Create the a process, the work is ok. So, I remove 'CLONE_VM' flag, the result also is right. But, what should I do if I want to use threads to achieve the same result?

Comment: @sonny_T "what should I do" -- you should accept this answer, and ask a new question, explaining what it is you are trying to achieve. See http://xyproblem.info.

Comment: @sonny_T I don't think a signal handler is a per-thread attribute. I.e., what I *think* you are trying to do probably isn't achievable. Any SIGSEGV handler will have to handle SIGSEGV for every thread in the process.